# Mock DbContext with FakeDbSets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking

I want to create a mocked `DbContext` using faked `DbSets`.
So I've created a class called `FakeDbSet<T>` which implements `IDbSet<T>`.

Now I've created a `FakeDbContext` which has those faked `DbSet<T>`s in it.
I've bound `DbContext` to `FakeDbContext` with Ninject like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<FakeDbContext>();
```

When I call my WebAPI project I'll get an `SqlException` that I don't have the permission to create the database.

This is my FakeDbContext:

```
public class FakeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<User> Users => new UserDbSet();
}
```

(Note: UserDbSet just fills the `HashSet<User>` with default data.)

How do I set my `FakeDbContext` to not create/interact with a *real* database? If I remove the `: DbContext` from the `FakeDbContext` Ninject says that it must be convertible to `DbContext`.

Comment: Have you thougth about a framework like Moq? http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed ith with qujck's help.

The reason why I was getting an exception because my DbContext tried to connect to the database was, that I was using `DbContext.Set<T>` which was accessing the database.

Overriding the `Set<T>` method fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling database initialisation

```
public class FakeDbContext : DbContext
{
    static FakeDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<FakeDbContext>(null);
    }

    public FakeDbContext() { }

    public virtual IDbSet<User> Users => new UserDbSet();
}
```

---

This test works for me:

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<RealContext>().To<FakeDbContext>();

    var result = kernel.Get<Wrapper>();

    var user = result.context.Users.Add(new User());
    Assert.NotNull(user);
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public readonly RealContext context;

    public Wrapper(RealContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}

public class RealContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<User> Users => new UserDbSet();
}

public class FakeDbContext : RealContext
{
    static FakeDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<FakeDbContext>(null);
    }

    public override IDbSet<User> Users => new UserDbSet();
}

// .....
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, but now I'm getting an error saying ```The underlying provider failed on Open.```. How do I disable all interaction with real tables and databases?

Comment: Does an empty constructor help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's stil trying to connect to the database on ```System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()```.

Comment: It's still trying to connect to that database. (I left the connectionString empty) Our problem is that we don't have a DB yet so we have to work with mocked data. How do I fix this?

Comment: It works with an empty constructor in my test project; i .e. I can create a `FakeDbContext` and add an instance of `User` to `Users`. Can you show the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Here's the Exception: http://pastebin.com/d77hXqms (Unfortunately some parts are in German)

Comment: How are you `new`ing up the `FakeDbContext`?

Comment: It's done by Ninject, I'm just injecting a ```DbContext``` into my services. In my question there's the line with the binding.